# @cacheable spring for redis , method specific ttl?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-annotations

I want to use redis as for caching my remote service request:response key :value pair using @Cacheable annotation

I know redis provides me the feature for having key specific expiry time.

Is there any provision in spring @Cacheable which allows me to use this redis feature.

Ideally , "ttl" should have been a property for @Cacheable annotation , but since not all caches support key specific ttl , spring might not have included ttl property.

As far as I have read, spring has suggested having different org.springframework.cache.CacheManager instances having different expiry time , but this seems like an overhead, given the fact that redis can already provides key specific expiry time with a single client instance.

Do you know any annotation/property/api using which I can set key specific(or method specific in case in @Cacheable) ttl when using @Cacheable annotation

Answer (score 1):

> The expiration time in seconds can be set with @RedisHash(timeToLive=…​)

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations)